# which techniques are used for these kinds of animations?

Tags: ios, animation, ios7

[Here](http://www.beyondkinetic.com/motion-ui-design-principles/) there are really, really great and helpful animations, which I'd love to learn. Which iOS-techniques are used to achieve those? UI Dynamics? A simple `[UIView animateWithDuration]`, Cocos2D or what?

Comment: I don't know the answer though but those are really cool animations :)

Comment: Most likely various as there are a lot of different techniques displayed.

Comment: It's a great link, but a pretty poor question. There are dozens of animations in there, all utterly different. How can this be answered?

Comment: @jrturton e.g. if someone recognizes only some animations, he/she could write "the one with the dots could be made with XY and the second one in context with ABC". I guess that's a way to answer this, right?

Comment: No, because that would only answer a small part of the question. A question has to be _specific_. For example, https://github.com/brocoo/BRFlabbyTable does one of them, but that couldn't be the accepted answer to this question. It's too broad.

Comment: no, that doesn't answer the question; I asked which techniques are used, a github-link is no answer to that. And I don't think there are a lot of different techniques used on that page, so in my opinion it's not too broad.

Comment: How about: _primarily opinion-based; Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: and, by the way - you preferred criticising the question instead of providing the link to github?

Comment: @Desdenova do you really think it's an opinion? I didn't ask for the *best* way to do something, but very specific: how are THOSE animations achieved? That's not an opinion, that's a fact...

Comment: Sorry, I strongly disagree. Answer to _how are THOSE animations achieved_ seems pretty much opinion based to me.

Comment: @swalkner yes, I'd prefer to criticise the question. It doesn't belong here. The github link isn't an answer, which is my whole point. An answer would be a book about custom animations and transitions, which means _the question is too broad_

Comment: noooooo, I also didn't ask HOW these animations are made, but which techniques are used. So you don't have to write a book about it but only write the keywords (Cocos2D? UIDynamics?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve such animations by playing and experimenting with `UI Dynamics` and with Simple `[UIView animateWithDuration]`.

Here are some useful links regarding **UIView** and **UI Dynamic** animations.

**1)** [View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html)

**2)** [Introduction to UIKit Dynamics.](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uikit-dynamics/)

**3)** [Animation in iOS.](http://www.slideshare.net/alexisgo1/animation-talk-trim)

**4)** [Custom Navigation Transitions & More](https://captechconsulting.com/blog/tyler-tillage/ios-7-tutorial-series-custom-navigation-transitions-more)

Hope this will helps you.